# C #define based in another #define error

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

So my Visual studio is declaring both tag1 and tag2 as undefined, but they are cleary defined, can't i define one based on the other?

```
#define push                99
#define last_instruction    push

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define new_instr   (1+last_instruction) //should be 100
    #undef  last_instruction
    #define last_instruction   new_instr    //redifine to 100 if debug
#endif
```

I have some cases with tag2 and it says that the definition must be const, but it is constant it is 1+99, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
BA

Comment: Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should try enabling the "Generate Preprocessed File" option (/P) to see what's going on.

Comment: Maybe `__COUNTER__` will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers provide I came up with a solution that although not perfect do best suit my case.

This implementation can be done in two forms:

Less changes in the future (only change 'last'):

```
#define push                   99
#define last                   push

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define new_instr          (1+last) 
    #define last_instruction   new_instr    
#else 
    #define last_instruction   last
#endif
```

OR

Clear Code but repeat 'push' in two places

```
#define push                   99

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define new_instr          (1+push) 
    #define last_instruction   new_instr    
#else 
    #define last_instruction   push
#endif
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you can't define the same macro twice. If you need to replace a macro, you first have to `#undef` it:

```
#define tag1    99
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define tag2   (1+tag1)
    #undef tag1
    #define tag1   tag2
#endif
```

But this will not solve the problem. Macros are not variables, you can't use them to store values to re-use at a later point. They are text replacement, so they sort of exist in parallel.

So the new definition `#define tag1 tag2` expands to `1+tag1`. But at this point, there is nothing called `tag1`, because we just undefined it and we are not yet done re-defining it.

Ponder this too much and you'll turn crazy :) So just forget about that whole thing, what you really want to do is this:

```
#define tag1_val  99
#define tag1      tag1_val

#ifdef DEBUG
    #undef tag1
    #define tag1  (tag1_val+1)
#endif
```

Comment: not working because i really need tag2... current:

    #define tag3    99
    
    #define tag1    tag3
    
    #ifdef DEBUG
        #define tag_help  (1+tag1)
        #define tag2   tag_help
        #undef tag1
        #define tag1          tag_help
    #endif

Comment: @BrunoMiguel That won't work either, for the reasons I tried to explain. Now if you need tag2, simply use my code and add `#define tag2 (tag1_val+1)`

Comment: i will edit the question to contemplate all the variables. Because what i really want is that tag1 to be dynamic based on the last tag...

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a few symbolic names for integer constants, you could define them in an `enum` like this:

```
enum {
    push = 99,
#ifdef DEBUG
    new_instr,
#endif
    last_plus_1,
    last_instr = last_plus_1 - 1
};
```

`new_instr` will be 100 (if `DEBUG` defined), `last_plus_1` will be either 101 (if `DEBUG` defined) or 100 (if `DEBUG` undefined), and `last_instr` will be one less than `last_plus_1`.